# is there a coffeescript auto compile / file watcher for windows?

Tags: coffeescript

I'd like to play around with integrating coffeescript into my dev process. But as I see it, I'll have to make a bat file that iterates a set of coffee files and spits out js files. Every time I write a bat file, useful as they may be, I ask myself: is there a better way?

Which makes me wonder: is there an app of some sort for Windows that will watch a directory or a file and spit out one/many js files when a coffee file is saved? I'm thinking of building one but don't want to reinvent the wheel. I looked around and found things that were similar but nothing that elevated it beyond "run this command line" on Windows.

Edit: already marked an answer, but looking at this 10 months later the answer is: [grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13769190/30946). Because it'll do a lot more than just auto-compile your coffeescript and you'll probably need to do more than just that to get your app going.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
coffee --watch -o lib -c src
```

where `src` is a directory containing your coffee files, and `lib` is your JavaScript output directory.

Answer (score 3):

*See update at bottom of post.*

I was hunting for the same thing the other day and came across this: https://github.com/danenania/CoffeePy

It's a simple python script that uses [`PyV8`](https://code.google.com/p/pyv8/) to run `coffee-script.js`.

It doesn't do anything fancy, just watches a folder recursively, and compiles any `.coffee` files whenever they're changed. It doesn't even have a bare option. These things could be very easily added though!

**Edit:**

I forked the script and added `--bare` and `--output` options.

You can get it here: https://github.com/johtso/CoffeePy

Comment: Is there a way the script can watch the directory for actual file changes? The timed polling method is kinda ghetto.

Comment: Polling is the only real cross platform solution I think.

Comment: Grunt is the real answer here. But for those still coming to the question who just want to compile coffee, look at http://koala-app.com/, which was created recently.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I prefer using build tools like grunt.js / yeoman or brunch for that purpose.

[grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/)
&
[grunt coffee](https://github.com/avalade/grunt-coffee)

Comment: I just started using grunt... grunt is definitely the right answer.

Comment: combine this with grunt-watch (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) and you have a winning combo :)

Answer (score 1):

Mindscape Workbench has a built in compiler/editor for VS 2010. Haven't tried it yet, but it looks like it'd be even better than a watcher/compiler. Scott Hanselman has a post about it here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CoffeeScriptSassAndLESSSupportForVisualStudioAndASPNETWithTheMindscapeWebWorkbench.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a simplier way just using -w option of coffeescript compiler

coffee -c -w *.coffee

This will compile all coffee files under the folder you are (put more file pathes if needed) each time you change one.

Comment: I think this is a recent addition or something -- seems unlikely I would have missed it back then. Also, your answer is essentially the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/6618475/30946

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: WebStorm 6. They've added a built in file-watcher for a variety of next-gen languages like SASS and Coffescript.

Comment: It works, but is very fragile and takes a while to get working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different way of doing it, this might help:
http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#scripts

If you include the coffeescript compiler on your page, you can include files with a "text/coffeescript" type and they will get compiled client-side.

Word of warning: Obviously, client-side compilation is not for something serious, but its completely fine for a small project/quick development.  It would then be trivial to compile them on the server and change the MIME-type and filename when something a bit quicker is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[**CoffeeScript-dotnet**](https://github.com/abolibibelot/coffeescript-dotnet#readme) does what you want, but it is a command line tool.

Command line tool for compiling CoffeeScript. Includes a file system watcher to automatically recompile CoffeeScripts when they change. Roughly equivalent to the coffee-script node package for linux / mac.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to do it:
Say your work is in "my-project-path" folder.

1. Go to the parent folder of "my-project-path"
2. Start a terminal and type `coffee -o my-project-path -cw my-project-path`

This line will watch and compile anything name as "*.coffee" in "my-project-path" folder, even if it is in "my-project-path/scripts/core" or "my-project-path/test/core".The js file will locate in the save folder as the .coffee file.