# How to: Coffeescript-Compiling in Aptana

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, aptana, compass-sass, blueprint

I installed Aptana, and i want to try Coffeescript. When I try to "Compile and display JS" it won´t work - console shows:

```
....xyz.sh: line 3: coffee: command not found
....xyz.sh: line 3: pre: command not found
```

I don´t get it - how do i get it to run?

Thank you!

**Edit:**

Since yesterday I managed to get compass/sass running in Aptana (yeah!) - so i realized that my question might be wrong: Do i have to tell Aptana (Windows?) where to find the compiler?

**Edit 2:**

Realized: The problem is - how can this gem be installed (in Aptana if possible):
via https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-coffeescript
I get an error when installing the guard gem:

```
ERROR:  Error installing guard:
    The 'ffi' native gem requires installed build tools.
```

Comment: Don't really help with your problem but the aptana support is a bit loosy, it's working for me but I still prefer a nodejs script watching a folder and auto compile on change - the best would be a vertical split with live preview like js2coffee.org

Comment: Thanks - i´m a designer by default and try to learn some new stuff. Problem is - there are different solutions, but a lot sounds Albanian to me. (Ruby, command-line-actions, nodeJs...) js2coffee is nice, if there is no better solution, i´ll use this.

Comment: If you're on windows you may be interested in that thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564928/is-there-a-coffeescript-auto-compile-file-watcher-for-windows ;)

Comment: Thanks - but i would have to use Phython for this, don´t i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some stuff here is a litte tutorial to setup compass and coffeescript for a project in Aptana:

(Info: I know very little about coding or ruby, so please be patient :) )

Create project ( i choose basic web template)

**Terminal:**

```
$ gem install compass
$ compass create myProject --using blueprint
```

check: 
http://compass-style.org/reference/blueprint/

You also have to setup some other stuff:
I found this page and followed it through..

https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-coffeescript

**Install bundle:**

```
$ gem install bundle
$ bundle init //to create the gemfile
```

**Install guard:**

You need to install Ruby Devkit before - check this links:

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

If you did so

```
$ gem install guard
$ gem install guard-coffeescript
```

I also installed **a JS-Engine** as recommended here:

https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-coffeescript#javascript-runtimes

```
$ gem install therubyrhino
```

**For Coffeescript:**

```
$ gem install coffee-script
$ gem install coffee-script-source
```

Then you have to edit the gemfile, mine looked like this:

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

# gem "rails"
group :development do
  gem 'guard'
end

group :development do
  gem 'guard-coffeescript'
end

group :development do
  gem 'therubyrhino'
end
```

run bundle

```
$ bundle
```

create guardfile

```
$ guard init
```

edit the guardfile

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard 'coffeescript', :input => 'myProject/coffeescript', :output => 'myProject/javascript'
```

you can start the guard with

```
$ guard start
```

This worked for me! If you see any mistakes please let me know!